# Understanding Java annotations

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I've looked around a bit, and I'm failing to understand parts of how Java annotation work.

All the examples I've seen so far create the annotation, then have a main method that runs through the classes in the project using reflection. Then they will do stuff with that and basically make the annotation work.

However I'm failing to understand how this works if I want to make my annotation project into a jar that I can include in another project, like jackson, guice, hibernate, etc. A main method wouldn't work in this case, right?

I've looked for some tutorials on how to make annotation that is done as an jar that my project can include, but I haven't found anything yet. Ideally I'd like to be able to use it inside a web framework such as spring or play.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main kinds of annotation you probably want to think about. The first kind is the runtime annotation. An example would be `@JsonIgnore` in Jackson.

```
class Test {
    @JsonIgnore private int num;
    private String str;
}
```

When the user passes a `Test` into your library code from their code, you use `getClass()` to inspect the annotations and do your magic. That is, when the user does

```
MyLibrary.doSomething(something)
```

you call `something.getClass()` and loop over the annotations somewhere inside `doSomething()`.

The other kind are compile time annotations, which are processed by annotation processors. An example would be `@Getter` from Project Lombok:

```
class Test {
    @Getter private final String name;
}
```

The annotation processor turns it into

```
class Test {
    private final String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

This is done when the user invokes `javac` (right before `javac` actually does compilation) and has your library JAR on the classpath. [Examples](http://hannesdorfmann.com/annotation-processing/annotationprocessing101)